# Select an element by title in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to activate a link calling the title as the element reference point:

```
<a href="#" title="dynamic title">Click me</a>
```

Im building a simple widget that will need to activate a link on another site. The link has no id or name tags.

I should also mention by activate I mean trigger the link.

The script loads an iframe and after loading I want it to trigger a set link on that page. In actual fact the code will need to trigger a series of links on the page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

    // autoclick
    $(document).ready(function(){
        document.frames["iframe"].$(".[title='title']").trigger('click');
        alert('bob');
    });
//-->
</script>

<iframe src="http://page.com" width="100%" height="50%" name="iframe" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need some Javascript/jQuery that will trigger a click on a link on another page to the one where the Javascript is? Sounds unpossible on a few levels.

Comment: No, he means a link towards an external website.

Comment: You're going to have to be more explicit. Where is this link relative to the script? On the page that includes it? Do you want the browser to follow the link? What behaviour do you expect?

Comment: added little more detail in the post about the nature of the widget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [attribute-equals selector `[name="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector):

```
$('a[name="dynamic title"]').click(function() {
    // event handling code here
});
```

Comment: ok thanks. And if i were triggering the link held within an iframe?

Answer (score 2):

`$('[title="dynamic title"]').click(function(){});`

You could also use wildcard selectors on the attribute values like so:

`$('[title*="some fragment"]').click(function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[title="dynamic title"]').click(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( 'a[title="dynamic title"]' ).click( function () {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you in your mission, but you can use jQuery's attribute selector to get a an element with a particular `title`:

```
$('a[title="dynamic title"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't trigger a link like that.

Calling `$('a[title="dynamic title"]').click()` will fire anything bound to the click event of the link, but won't actually cause the browser to follow the link.