# Using onclick based on title of span tag

Tags: jquery

I have some span tags where I want to be able to click them and toggle a div. I cannot put ID's on the span tags. How might I do this based on title on the spans those are unique?  Here is my HTML.

```
<span title="Silver" class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview">
        <span style="background-color:#cccccc;" class="swatchColour swatchColour_1">&nbsp;</span>
</span>
<span title="Black" class="swatchColours swatchOneColour showPreview">
        <span style="background-color:#000000;" class="swatchColour swatchColour_2">&nbsp;</span>
</span>
<div id="colour_one">Silver</div>
<div id="colour_two">Black</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select an element by title in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431891/select-an-element-by-title-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('span[title="Silver"]').click(function(){
    $('#colour_one').toggle();
});


$('span[title="Black"]').click(function(){
    $('#colour_two').toggle();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/XYfZV/

Comment: Please don't post incomplete answ

Comment: It wasn't incomplete. He wanted to know how to select the span with the unique title. I showed the selector, then figured I might as well just code it all.

Comment: The important part was `$('span[title="Silver"]')`. That's all he needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('span.swatchColours').on('click', function() {
    var that = $(this);

    if(that.attr('title') == 'Silver') 
        $('div#colour_one').toggle();
    else if(that.attr('title') == 'Black')            
        $('div#colour_two').toggle();           

});
```